# Find point farthest on $(x-5)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-7)^2=69$ from point $(2, 3, -6)$

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

So, I have the equation of a sphere $$(x-5)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-7)^2=69$$ and a point, $P(2, 3, -6)$. I am supposed to find the point on the sphere farthest away from $P$.

I tried to figure out how to use parametric equations to represent the sphere and maximize that using the distance formula. However, they are multiple variables in this equation, and this led me to nowhere.

Comment: __Hint:__ Join the center of the sphere to the point. Then the point on the sphere farthest away from P lies on this line.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=point%2C%20farthest%2C%20from%2C%20sphere&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

The line connecting $P(2,3,-6)$ and the farthest point $M(a,b,c)$ is parallel to $M$’s normal surface vector $(a-5,b+1,c-7)$, i.e.
$$\frac{a-2}{a-5}=\frac{b-3}{b+1}=\frac{c+6}{c-7}$$

Substitute into $(a-5)^2+(b+1)^2+(c-7)^2=69$ to obtain the point
$$M\left(5+3\sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}, -1-4\sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}, 7+13\sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The center of the sphere is $C(5,-1,7)$. The line passing through $C$ and $P(2,3,-6)$ has parametric equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x=5+(2-5)t&x=5-3t\\
y=-1+(3-(-1))t&y=-1+4t\\
z=7+(-6-7)t&z=7-13t\\
\end{cases}
$$
Substitute in the equation of the sphere
$$(x-5)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-7)^2=69$$
$$(5-3t-5)^2+(-1+4t+1)^2+(7-13t-7)^2=69$$
$$194 t^2 = 69\to t=\pm\sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}$$
the point on the sphere farthest away from $P$ is:
$$\left(3 \sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}+5,-2 \sqrt{\frac{138}{97}}-1,13 \sqrt{\frac{69}{194}}+7 \right)$$